# 302 redirect to HTTPS is occuring no matter what! WHY?? IIS/ASP.net/Ektron

Tags: iis, https, http-status-code-302

Spent hours looking at this.. hoping someone has an idea..

I have an Ektron site on the internet.. For some reason now when you goto the home page the first thing it does is a 302 redirect to the https version of the site.. We create a blank test.html file on the root and it STILL does that.. So I guess that means it must be the IIS server..

Any ideas what is forcing this?? When I am on the machine itself and I browse it it works fine.. but from the outside it keep going to the https

Comment: Use Fiddler to inspect http request when accessing from outside, and post it here (clean sensitive data).

Comment: 8 hours looking into this.. end of the day.. then.. We get this email.. LOL!!

Comment: oops. didnt finish.. funny story.. turns out they told my PM 3 weeks ago that they were turning on SSL for the entire site.. The pm forgot about this until the work day was over and the client reminded her. SIGH

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, usually it is set in IIS/web.config to always use SSL for site. But you mentioned that it does that only when accessed from outside, so it seems like some proxy/network setting.